# What is the vim command to copy paste a line 'n' no. of times with the numbers in the lines getting incremented consecutively?

Tags: vim

What is the vim command to copy paste the following line 'n' no. of times with the 3 digit numbers(in this case, "001") in the lines getting incremented consecutively? :

`test abc_001 {
a_script : "run_script.sh -unit_test_number 001";
details: <text> Test: a , pattern: 001  </text>;
count : 1;         };`

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy,_cut_and_paste

Answer (score 1):

- First you yank (<kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>y</kbd>) the lines, and then paste (<kbd>p</kbd>).
- Then, execute this:

  ```
  :'[,']s/\d\d\d/\=printf("%03d",1+submatch(0))
  ```

The command is gonna change the `001` into `002` in the just pasted text.

You can create your own mapping/macro if you use this often enough.

Comment: Yes it does...but I need something using which I can copy the lines multiple times & then change the 3-digit-numbers in them in the ascending order.

Comment: @Sara as I said, record a macro: yank, paste, do `:s...` then yank the edited text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a macro. Suppose the sample input paragraph is:

```
abc_001
number 001
pattern: 001
```

Save this sequence of commands into a register (e.g. register `a`):

```
yip}p/\d\d\d^M^An^An^A
```

Here `^M`, and `^A` are special characters for `<Enter>` and `Ctrl+A`. Put cursor in input paragraph and run the macro twice (by typing `2@a` in normal-mode). Output:

```
abc_001
number 001
pattern: 001

abc_002
number 002
pattern: 002

abc_003
number 003
pattern: 003
```

Comment: Hello..I did the same, unfortunately it copies the same thing & doesn't increment the numbers consecutively.

Comment: Note that `^M` character is obtained by typing `<c-v><Enter>`, or in other words `Ctrl+V` then `Enter`. Similarly `^A` is obtained with `<c-v><c-a>` that is `Ctrl+V` then `Ctrl+A`.  Select `yip}p/\d\d\d^M^An^An^A` in visual mode and copy into register with: `"ay`